# crash when using EKEventEditViewController

Tags: cocoa-touch, ios4, ios5

I have a weird crash that I don't know how to debug...
Here is the code:

```
-(void) addEventButtonPressed:(UIButton*)button{
DLog(@"Add new event");
// If event is nil, a new event is created and added to the specified event store. New events are 
// added to the default calendar. An exception is raised if set to an event that is not in the 
// specified event store.
// When add button is pushed, create an EKEventEditViewController to display the event.
EKEventEditViewController *addController = [[EKEventEditViewController alloc] initWithNibName:nil bundle:nil];

// set the addController's event store to the current event store.
addController.eventStore = self.eventStore;
addController.editViewDelegate = self;

// present EventsAddViewController as a modal view controller
[self presentModalViewController:addController animated:YES];
```

}

My app crashes after a looong time at this line:
[self presentModalViewController:addController animated:YES];

I am using ARC.
Any clues?
Thanks!

My console says just `EXC_BAD_ACCESS(code=2, address=0xbf7ffff4)`

[EDIT] It seems `eventStore` needs to be initialized before passing it to `addController` or you get a crash. In my case it was nil.

Comment: what do you read on the console?

Comment: just EXC_BAD_ACCESS, but it takes a long time to get there.. like out of memory or something)

Answer (score 2):

Make sure that you are presenting the EKEventEditViewController from the main thread; it will crash (not always, but usually) if you present it from a secondary thread.